# 1fr grid cell expands past 100%

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following grid which I want to span for exactly the height of the screen - not less, not more. In the grid, I have a fixed header (one), a fixed footer (three) and a scrollable content (two)

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "one"
        "two"
        "three"
        ;
    grid-template-rows: 33px 1fr 34px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

What happens is that if the content inside `two` gets too large, the height of the entire grid is now larger than the viewport. As a result, my footer gets pushed down, while I would like instead to scroll the content and keep the footer where it is.

I know I can achieve what I want with `position: fixed`, but this is a trimmed-down example of a more complex grid. Any help is appreciated, I prefer to keep the grid approach if at all possible. I put together a fiddle for your convenience. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/x6stfc01/1/

HTML For your convenience

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two">
    Start of Content
    <div style="height: 5000px"></div>
    End of Content
  </div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add `overflow-y: scroll` to the `two` item or `overflow-y: auto` (even better)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one" "two" "three";
  grid-template-rows: 33px 1fr 34px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  background-color: blue;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two">
      Start of Content
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>      End of Content
    </div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```